# CAMediaTimingFunction with opacity animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a UIView in which I want to animate the opacity to 0 in 10 seconds. However, the animation should start after 7.5 seconds. This is because I am animating a frame change first, and the UIView should fade out only the last 1/4 duration of the animation. This is my try:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let x = UIView()
    view.addSubview(x)
    x.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    x.backgroundColor = .black

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0, 0, 0, 1)
    animation.fromValue = 1
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.duration = 10
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

    x.layer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")

}
```

The UIView just instantly fades out. How can I delay it with mediaTimingFunction?

Comment: The timing function is used to control the pacing of an animation when it is in progress. It cannot create a delay. Use beginTime to create a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Set the duration to 2.5 seconds and start the animation 7.5 seconds after you begin the frame animation

```
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 7.5
```